# NSFetchedResultsController and to-many relationship not working

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, swift3, nssortdescriptor

Ok, I was searching and trying in that case for the last 1-2 weeks and I didn't get it work. I would be able to achieve what I want without NSFRC but for performance reasons and convienience I would like to do it with the NSFRC. 
So, I have a DataModel with 2 Entities - see the picture 
[image: to-many Relationship]

There is one Account and one account can have many accountchanges - which is quite obvious. 
So I want to be able to choose an Account and then show all AccountChanges for that specific Account. 
So far I was able to get the Account and also accessing the NSSet in cellForRow Function but I am not getting the correct sections and numberOfRowsInSection - this is the main issue.

Here is some code:

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    print("Sections : \(self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count)")
    if (self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count)! <= 0 {
        print("There are no objects in the core data - do something else !!!")
    }
    return self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("Section Name")
    print(self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section].name)
    let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
    print("Section: \(sectionInfo) - Sections Objects: \(sectionInfo.numberOfObjects)")
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
}
```

There are some print statements which are only for information!

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let myCell = myTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell")! as UITableViewCell
    let accountBalanceChanges = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    print("AccountBalanceChanges from cell....")
    print(accountBalanceChanges)

    let details = accountBalanceChanges.accountchanges! as NSSet
    print("Print out the details:")
    print(details)
    let detailSet = details.allObjects
    let detailSetItem = detailSet.count // Just for information!


    let myPrint = detailSet[indexPath.row] as! AccountChanges
    let myVal = myPrint.category

    myCell.textLabel?.text = myVal

    return myCell
}
```

So, I am able to get the data but always only one item and not the whole set - I guess due to the fact that the sections/ numberOfRows are wrong.

Here is my NSFRC

```
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Accounts> {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Accounts> = Accounts.fetchRequest()
    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "aName", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]


    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(ANY accountchanges.accounts = %@)", newAccount!)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".

    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.coreDataStack.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    do {
        try _fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
    } catch {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        let nserror = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}
```

I am assuming it is the SortDescriptor or the predicate - or maybe both?

Any help or at least directions are well appreciated. 
I already tried many different approaches but none was giving me the correct results.

Comment: One more comment, I tried lots of different paths in SortDescriptor and in the predicate/ or the sectionNameKeyPath of NSFRC - most failure message are: "to-many key is not allowed here" or "keypath for (category, title...) does not exist" From above code, the predicate seems to work but the SortDescriptor is giving me the most problems...my guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the opposite, I mean using the FRC to fetch all the changes for an account with a certain Id, and use the following predicate:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "accounts.aId = %@", ACCOUNTID)
```

or

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "accounts = %@", account.objectID)
```

I would rename Accounts entity to Account and same for the relationship since it's a to-one relationship.
That's assuming you have a table view with all the accounts and when you click on one it gives you back its changes.

```
 var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<AccountChanges> {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<AccountChanges> = AccountChanges.fetchRequest()
    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "aName", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]


    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "accounts.aId = %@", ACCOUNTID)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".

    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.coreDataStack.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    do {
        try _fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
    } catch {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        let nserror = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}
```

Cheers

Comment: I thought about that as well but then I really don't need any relationships as I could just pass in the accountID to every account change. But since we are having the option to use relationships I wanted to do it that way. Anyway, if no other solution I might do it that way and refactor. I already have a unique ID in both of my database and I can do it that way but again, it would be nice to get it work with relationship and NSFRC.
Thanks for your suggestion...

Comment: My suggestion still involve relationships and NSFRC. you just have to fetch the other way around. Instead of fetching the Accounts and try to access the changes from it, fetch all the changes for the account with ID that you pass on the predicate.

Comment: That is not working, it is only a one-to-one from account changes to Accounts - can't change that as one account change can only affect one account. There is only a one-to-many from accounts to accountchanges - see the pic. And as I wrote above, the predicate is not the problem, it is the SortDescriptor or the keyPath in NSFRC. I get the correct account but the count of the changes is wrong in sections/ numberOfRows.... 
And as said before, I can do all that without NSFRC - so the problem is not the fetching itself, it is the fetching with NSFRC because you get back an NSSet form the rel.

Comment: With the sortDescriptor in your code it is not working as this key relates to the Accounts Database, I already tried your approach....

Comment: I forgot to change the sort descriptor. the sort descriptor anyway it's not your problem. it is just used to sort. Also, the NSFRC relies on the predicate so your predicate is probably wrong. you could easily access its property fetchedObjects to see if all the results you're expecting from the fetch are returned.

Comment: Again "it is not working" because of the sort descriptor - I tried it 100 times with different approaches and if you read again, I only have a one to one from accountchanges to accounts - how will you know how many changes an account has if you look for the account coming from accountchanges where you save them actually? I need to come from Accounts with the accountchanges relationship - this is a must! Otherwise you will never know about the changes - again and again, I did all that fetching already without NSFRC....

Comment: 1. If you have a screen with all the accounts and if you click on one and the next screen shows the changes you can as I described. If you have a different flow it's another story. 2. try to set the sectionNameKeyPath of the NSFRC. Good luck

Comment: I exactly do have that in my project app and I promise you, it is not working, this is why I posted it here... just try for yourself. And is like you write by yourself, you must come with an Account to fetch the changes and not the other way round...

Comment: I got it working with your help, it is also working by passing in the actual account - thanks for you help and directions!